# Write cloud code in Parse to check for unique username - Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to check if an username is unique in the Installation class of my Parse collection. I figured out that the installation class cannot be queried like the normal classes and should be cloud coded to obtain result.

I had seen this post. [How to check Unique fields in a class using cloud code.](https://www.parse.com/questions/unique-fields--2) I don't know how to replace this with what I require and make a call from my android device.

My requirement is that, I just need to check if a given username is already present in the Installation class or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is probably the one described in the post you linked to. You shouldn't try to determine the uniqueness of the name on the device - you should do it on the server side while creating a new instance of your installation class, and return an error to the app if it tries to create a username that already exists (like in the example you posted).

Comment: Ya thats what I try to do, But I dont know how to change that code to check in Installation class and how to pass the username from Android device to the cloud code.